# Information on the Elderwood Project/Platform

Tags: attacks, phishing, attack-vector, zero-day, cyber-warfare

I've read [Symantec's whitepaper](https://www.symantec.com/content/en/us/enterprise/media/security_response/whitepapers/the-elderwood-project.pdf) on the Elderwood Project and the [blog update on the Elderwood Platform](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/how-elderwood-platform-fueling-2014-s-zero-day-attacks). They both make for a very interesting read, especially in the zero-day exploit meta-analysis that found the Elderwood Platform.

Does anyone know of, or have a bibliography on Elderwood?

Comment: Isn't this a question for Symantec?

Comment: http://www.symantec.com/connect/blog-tags/elderwood

Comment: @schroeder No, it is not a question for Symantec. Symantec published a whitepaper in 2012 and an update via blog post in 2014. The other blog posts are basically extracts from the whitepaper. It is widely believed that Operation Aurora was conducted by the Elderwood Group. However, the 2014 blog post indicated that there Elderwood platform is being distributed or reused by others.

Comment: But Symantec identified them (and named them?) - the details need to come from them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question for Symantec. Symantec identified them - the details need to come from them.

Comment: @AviD, Symantect named them based upon a variable used in several variations of the platform. Panda Security discovered and named the Conficker Worm, does that mean that questions about Conficker are off-topic? The questions is about a sophisticated malware platform, not about the name nor the initial discoverer.